# C++ strtok function split words

Tags: c++, function, split, cpu-word, strtok

i am to write a function called splitLine() in c++.
can someone please help? im really confused

```
splitLine () {

    string temp = aLine;
    string *tempLine =  strtok(temp, " ");
    free(temp)
    countNum = sizeOf(tempLine);

   }
```

Comment: It should probably accept a `string` as an argument.

Comment: in another file it already declared a string aLine. which can be manipulated with pointers

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the instructions.

The `strtok` function operates on nul terminated char arrays (aka C strings) not C++ strings. So create a temporary 'string' actually means this

```
// create temporary string which is a copy of aLine
char* temp = new char[aLine.size() + 1];
strcpy(temp, aLine.c_str());

// extract words from temp
...

// free temporary string
delete[] temp;
```

Breaking the temporary string into words with `strtok` means writing a *loop*. `strtok` will extract one word at a time. I'm sure you can find examples of this on the internet. So I'll leave that to you.

Comment: sorry my english is not very good actually. thank you so much for you help. it explains a lot but i dont quite understand what do you mean by extract words from temp

Comment: Turn `"The quick brown fox"` into `"The" "quick" "brown" "fox"`.